# Can the force be used to move something as large as a moon, planet, asteroid, star, etc.?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

I guess what I'm really asking is if there is a limit on what the force can be used to do. Curious though, is it possible for a single force sensitive to muster up enough force power to move something extremely large and massive like a planet? Also, what is the most powerful use of the force in canon and legends?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/32583/51379

Comment: So this question has been marked as a duplicate of a question that is itself marked as a duplicate of two separate questions, one of which has been closed as "not constructive". Is closed-answer-ception something we're ok with on this site? Seems a bit weird to me.